# Installing subclipse on Aptana Studio 3 fails

Tags: aptana, subclipse

I'm trying to install subclipse 1.6.x onto Aptana Studio 3 (build 3.0.7.201112151935). It isn't working cause once I've clicked that I accept the licence agreements the finish button doesn't light up.

I've tried rolling back the configuration history, closing and reopening and installing 1.8.x. 1.8.x worked once, but isn't compatible with my SVN repo so that's no use.

Any guesses/solutions?

Thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: You say 1.8.x is not compatible with your server.  I am a SVN committer and own the Subclipse project.  That answer really isn't possible.  Any SVN 1.x client can work with any 1.x server.  The main issue is that this is SVN 1.7.x client and you need to provide the native libraries for JavaHL.  They come with Subclipse for Windows, but you must get them elsewhere for other OS.

Comment: @Mark: So there is a Subclipse plugin for Helios that's compatible with SVN 1.7.x? Because I thought 1.7.x support was only available for Indigo (the helios update site only has Subclipse 1.6.x), which is unfortunate as the standalone version of Aptana Studio 3 is built on Helios, and I haven't been able to find a way to upgrade it.

Comment: I think you are confusing Subclipse and Subversive.  Subclipse only has a single update site and it supports Eclipse 3.2+.  The update site URL is http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

Comment: @Mark: You're right, I was. =P I just uninstalled Subversive and installed Subclipse 1.8 from that update site and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Eclipse where the Finish button does not show up.  It was fixed, but maybe Aptana is not using the latest version.  I seem to recall you could click Back and then Next and the button would enable.

Here are some Eclipse bugs on this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=136907

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149300

Comment: Tried bouncing backwards and forwards and it's not playing sadly.

Comment: I can confirm this bug. I was able to get it to work by exiting the update/install software dialog completely and then opening it up and re-attempting to install the plugin. I believe this happens when there is an update or transfer (SFTP/SVN) occurring in the background while you attempt to install new plugins.

Comment: Still hitting this issue with aptana 3.2.2 wtf.  Unfortunately, back, next isn't working....

Answer (score 0):

For me I found that there were sub-packages which couldn't be installed.

Bad Components:

- Mylyn
- Revision graph

These were identified as *bad* on the sub-components selection screen, however, when this is done, and the licenses are accepted, the "Finish" button does not get highlighted.

I Found that if you remove this *bad* components on the initial "Available Software" screen  (and *not* on the sub-componets selection screen) and continue, that you the "Finish" button gets highlighted and you can proceed with installation.